# Most efficient way of doing column wise subtraction in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge DataFrame in Spark that looks like this on (except of fact, that it have much more Value# columns):

```
Group     Type  Value#1  Value#2  Value#3
   G1  Revenue       11       22       33
   G2  Revenue       12       23       34
   G3  Revenue       13       24       35
   G4  Revenue       14       25       36
   G5  Revenue       15       26       37
   G1    Costs        1        1        1
   G2    Costs        2        2        2
   G3    Costs        3        3        3
   G4    Costs        4        4        4
   G5    Costs        5        5        5
```

Again, actual dataframe contains 120 Value# columns.

What I need is for every Group type in Rows and Value# in Columns calculate Revenue - Costs.

Output should look like next one:

```
Group    Type  Value#1  Value#2  Value#3
   G1  Profit       10       11       22
   G2  Profit       10       11       22
   G3  Profit       10       11       22
   G4  Profit       10       11       22
   G5  Profit       10       11       22
```

P.S. I'm using Spark 2.1 from Python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your DataFrame into two based on the `Type` column. Then join the two filtered DataFrames and do the subtraction:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

value_columns = [c for c in df.columns if c not in {'Group', 'Type'}]
df.where("Type = 'Revenue'").alias("rev")\
    .join(df.where("Type = 'Costs'").alias('cost'), on=["Group"])\
    .select(
        "Group",
        f.lit("Profit").alias("Type"),
        *[(f.col("rev."+c)-f.col("cost."+c)).alias(c) for c in value_columns]
    )\
    .show()
#+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+
#|Group|  Type|Value#1|Value#2|Value#3|
#+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+
#|   G2|Profit|     10|     21|     32|
#|   G3|Profit|     10|     21|     32|
#|   G4|Profit|     10|     21|     32|
#|   G5|Profit|     10|     21|     32|
#|   G1|Profit|     10|     21|     32|
#+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```